# install Office Interops without Office on the server

Tags: excel, interop

I am working with changing excel cells using Excel Interop.

I have tried with many open source solutions but the file is corrupted while reading. Therefore, I am stick on using Excel Interop.

When developing on the server, I got this problem:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Therefore, I would like to install Office interop on my server: `http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18346`

However, when I install it, I got this problem:

"Please install Microsoft Office 2007 before installing this product"

My question is: would it be possible to install the interop without the office 2007 on the server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Office Interop is only a .NET means to access the (COM) Office components. So they have to be there, or the Office Interop has no reason to be there.

If you want to develop applications that read/write Office files, you may use OpenXML (see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) and the unofficial ClosedXML (http://closedxml.codeplex.com/)  or third-party components such as SmartXLS (http://www.smartxls.com/).